# How to obtain Bluetooth LE Appearance on Android using ScanRecord.getAdvertisingDataMap or is it possible that way?

Tags: java, android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to obtain Appearance data of Bluetooth Low Energy devices in Android (in a Flutter app but seemingly iOS doesn't provide appearance, so I'm focusing on Android). ScanRecord has a https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord#getAdvertisingDataMap() function, however what can I use to index that dictionary?

I tried to talk with Bard and first it wanted me to tediously dig in the byte array returned by https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord#getBytes(). I'm not sure if that's a hallucination though, but I have a feeling I should use `getAdvertisingDataMap` instead of digging in a raw byte array.

Bard hallucinated a non existent constant to index into the dictionary, and says I cannot use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord#DATA_TYPE_APPEARANCE, is that true?

My concept:

```
int getAppearance(ScanResult result) {
  ScanRecord scanRecord = result.getScanRecord();
  Map<Integer, byte[]> advertisingDataMap = scanRecord.getAdvertisingDataMap();
  int appearance = 0;
  if (advertisingDataMap.containsKey(ScanRecord.DATA_TYPE_APPEARANCE)) {
    byte[] appearanceBytes = advertisingDataMap[ScanRecord.DATA_TYPE_APPEARANCE];
    appearance = appearanceBytes[0] * 256 + appearanceBytes[1];
  }

  return appearance;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code section in my question actually works. However unfortunately only on API Level 33+, so Android 13 and above. Probably that's why I haven't found examples about it (it's too new?) and Bard was insistent on `.getBytes()`.

However what Bard was advising was a simple loop which didn't care about the actual structure of the advertising data, so it was simply searching for the 0x19 (`ScanRecord.DATA_TYPE_APPEARANCE`) value. That would be incorrect if the appearance would follow some other data where the payload would accidentally contain that same byte. We'd instead need to intelligently stride when looking for the payload.

Another StackOverflow entry shows the info about the data structure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043510/292502 with some example code which interprets the whole byte array. Probably Google integrated some similar algorithm and made it available as the `getAdvertisingDataMap()`. Here is another generic example: https://github.com/DrJukka/BLETestStuff/blob/master/MyBLETest/app/src/main/java/org/thaliproject/p2p/mybletest/BLEBase.java

Since I'm only looking for the appearance, here is the code I'm trying to PR into the Flutter Blue Plus plugin:

```
        ScanRecord scanRecord = scanResult.getScanRecord();
        int appearance = 0;
        if (scanRecord != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) { // Android 13
                Map<Integer, byte[]> advertisingDataMap = scanRecord.getAdvertisingDataMap();
                if (advertisingDataMap.containsKey(ScanRecord.DATA_TYPE_APPEARANCE)) {
                    byte[] appearanceBytes = advertisingDataMap.get(ScanRecord.DATA_TYPE_APPEARANCE);
                    appearance = appearanceBytes[1] * 256 + appearanceBytes[0];
                }
            } else {
                byte[] scanRecordBytes = scanRecord.getBytes(); // From API Level 21
                int byteIndex = 0;
                while (byteIndex < scanRecordBytes.length) {
                    int length = scanRecordBytes[byteIndex];
                    // Zero value indicates that we are done with the record now
                    if (length <= 0) break;

                    if (length + byteIndex >= bytes.length) {
                        break;
                    }

                    byteIndex += 1;
                    int dataType = scanRecordBytes[byteIndex];
                    // If the data type is zero, then we are pass the significant
                    // section of the data, and we are done
                    if (dataType == 0) break;

                    if (dataType == 0x00000019) { // ScanRecord.DATA_TYPE_APPEARANCE magic byte
                        appearance = scanRecordBytes[byteIndex + 2] * 256 + scanRecordBytes[byteIndex + 1];
                    }

                    byteIndex += length;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I know that reading the [specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-4/) is not very popular, but it is a very good source of reliable information and, last but not least, it is free.

Answer (score 0):

The bandwidth of Bluetooth Advertising PDUs is limited and most AD elements are optional. It is therefore (very) rare for a device to insert its Appearance AD element into the Advertising PDU.

So I think your code might work in general, but you won't get a result because most devices don't broadcast this information.

In general, a "fingerprinting" approach could work well for such functionality. If you use a tool like [nRF Connect for Mobile](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) you could take a look at how it was implemented there.

Comment: The question was induced by a software dealing with fitness BLE gadgets. Many heart rate straps, cycling cadence / speed sensors, power meters, etc. have the appearance set. Not all, but way more than just "very rare". This helps me to set apart for example a speed sensor from a cadence sensor without connecting to it. I spotted the appearance in the nRF Connect app first time BTW. What kind of fingerprinting nRF Connect uses? Do you have some pointers for the implementation you say?

Comment: And the bandwidth of the appearance in the advertising is extremely low: 1 length byte, 1 type byte and 2 data bytes, that's 4 bytes. The service is way more for example. IMHO if a device doesn't have appearance is rather 2 reasons: 1. It's not important for that device (so it's not like a cycling speed or cadence sensor). 2. Cost cutting while developing the embedded hardware and the software - rather the engineers didn't have bandwidth to deal with fluffy features. But major manufacturers like WAHOO, Garmin, etc. more likely to have just enough juice to develop a half decent hw + firmware.

Comment: @CsabaToth we seem to have completely different applications. I'm collecting BLE advertising PDUs as I cycle and drive around my area, and I find the Appearance  AD element in much less than one in a thousand advertising PDUs.

Comment: In terms of bandwidth, those 4 bytes are much more than 10% of the available payload of the Advertising PDU. It only contains static data that never changes, which makes it ridiculously superfluous over time, and in my opinion that is a waste of time and energy, at least for mobile devices :-D

Comment: Time and energy. As I outlined by some scenarios appearance allows to make decisions about a device *without* connecting to them. Waste of time and energy is to have to connect, request services and read characteristics to make decisions. Many seconds of time, and also waay more bytes and energy. It's quite contrary to useless. For you it must be even more important to not have to connect than me. A quick scan around me: I see 4 devices (a cycling sensor and 3 HRMs) w appearance. My HRM: 49 bytes adv, not my HRM (neighbor's wrist watch): 56 bytes adv. 4 bytes = 7-8% of adv length.

Comment: I'm still curious what fingerprinting the nRF Connect would use, because that could be a fallback when there's no appearance (some cycling sensors don't supply it), and I do not want to connect and poll services / characteristics just for a scan.

Comment: If you're using active scanning, then you're combining the payload of 2 advertising PDUs and that's how you get the numbers you've seen. But this also means that you're sending additional messages and not just listening to the advertising PDUs of other devices.

Comment: Regarding the fingerprinting approach, it seems to me that the app examines the AD elements and their content to render an appropriate icon for the Advertising PDU. See screenshot:https://hackster.imgix.net/uploads/attachments/1246357/screenshot_20210118-165041_nrf_connect1_mztdDX8o5r.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&w=1280&h=960&fit=max
Nordic Semiconductor releases a lot of their software as open source, but I don't know if the application is part of that source code.

Comment: I'm not sure if nRF use any fingerprinting or not, but simply looking at the service UUIDs advertised by the device is enough: 0xFEAA means an Eddystone type beacon. Appearance or *other* advertisement data can get into the picture when those service UUIDs are not present or not descriptive enough. For nRF Connect can also simply decide the icon to be a bicycle crank arm or bicycle when it sees the 0x1816 GATT service. For it doesn't matter if it's actually speed or cadence sensor or both. For me it matters.

Comment: The app in question is actually a Flutter one, and the Android layer uses the "built-in" BLE API calls provided by Android. Seems like Android uses active scan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994776/android-ble-passive-scan. That's not bothersome, because I don't care if I request a response packet or not, it'll be still 100x less resource intensive than to actually connect to devices and iterate services, characteristics...